# Formatting div and span elements

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle I am trying to format:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/35/)

I am looking for following things:

- Some distance between `logo` and `text` divs. If I use `margin-top` property doesn't work relatively.
- spans under the `text` div with a line break. Separating these spans with a `<br/>` gives more distance then needed. If I change the `line-height property` it creates problem for other spans. I am hoping that I don't have specify `line-height` for each `span`.

Comment: Your code will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your Jfiddle:

```
.box {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FF0000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px; 
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -o-border-radius:5px;
  -ms-border-radius:5px;
}
.logo{
    width:80%;
    margin:0% 4% 0% 15%;  
    font-size:20px;   
}
.inlineDiv{
    display:inline-block; 
    width:48%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.inlineDiv > img{
    float:right;   
}
#text{
     text-align:center;   
}
```

EDIT:

further html:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="logo">
  <div class="inlineDiv">
   <img src="c:\work\img\logo3.jpg" width="80" height="80" />
  </div>
  <div class="inlineDiv">
      <span class="spanTop">
          <p>YAD</p>
          <p>HIM</p>
      </span>
  </div>
   </div>
     <div id='text'>
         <span class="tag">
             <p>Try this now with the</p>
             <p> help of something then</p>
         </span>
  </div>
```

​

Comment: just replacing your css with existing CSS didn't work at all. Just to confirm again logo div is perfectly fine. I just need text div with some top margin with logo div and no top or bottom margin between text spans.

Comment: oh yea I change the html too lol

Comment: nope :( Check this out and you will see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/37/

Comment: well to change the 'line height' do `p

Comment: `#logo > p{ margin:0px;}` and same for the others but your's are still spans so use `span` instead of `p`.

Answer (score 2):

The `margin` property is your answer. Put your text into paragraph tags within the span and customise their margins like so

```
p, span, div[name="logo"] {
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
}
```

The margins are set in a circular clockwise method. `margin: 'top' 'right' 'bottom' 'left';`

Comment: It didn't work perfectly. I want span text up and down with no space.
http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/36/

Comment: then change it! lol `margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;` will get rid of all your margins, but you may need to do the same with your `padding`. I'll check out the Jfiddle and make a better answer.